# Javascript binary search from 0 to 100 from user input

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a simple JavaScript guessing game.  First, a user inputs a number (between 0 and 100) and the computer will try to guess it. Here is the code that I have written, but it's not working correctly.  Any ideas.  Thanks in advance.

```
<p>Enter a number between <strong>0</strong> and <strong>100</strong> and remember your number.</p>
<p>When ready press "Begin" and the computer will try to find your number.</p>
<input id="myNumber" style="width: 100px" />
<button id="guess" onclick="compGuess">Begin</button>

function compGuess()
{
    if (document.getElementById("myNumber").value < 0 || document.getElementById("myNumber").value > 100 )
    {
        alert("Please enter a number between 0 and 100.");
    } 
    else
    {
        var start = 0;
        var stop  = 100;
        var middle = Math.floor(start + stop / 2);
        var guess = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;

        if (middle == guess)
        {
            alert("Your number is: " + middle);
        }
        else
        {
            while (start <= stop)
            {
                if (middle < guess)
                {
                    start = middle + 1;

                }
                else if (middle > guess)
                {
                    stop = middle - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(middle); 
                }
                alert("Your answer is : " + middle);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What *does* it do when it "doesn't work correctly"? Nothing? Finds the wrong number?

Comment: it does nothing...the alert boxes don't pop up. Sorry.

Comment: can you provide your html also ?

Comment: I think you have other problems as well, but you're forgetting order of operations: `var middle = Math.floor(start + stop / 2);` that doesn't do what you think it does. Remember 6th grade, PEMDAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a number of problems. The end condition for your while loop didn't really make sense. As others have said, your calculation of `middle` was wrong and was only performed once. I think this code should get you what you want:

```
function compGuess()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value, 10);
    if (value < 0 || value > 100 )
    {
        alert("Please enter a number between 0 and 100.");
    } 
    else
    {
        var start = 0;
        var stop  = 100;
        var middle = Math.floor(start + (stop - start) / 2);
        var guess = value;

        if (middle == guess)
        {
            alert("Your number is: " + middle);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('Middle: ' + middle);
            while (middle != guess)
            {
                console.log('');
                if (middle < guess)
                {
                    start = middle + 1;
                    middle = Math.floor(start + (stop - start) / 2);
                }
                else if (middle > guess)
                {
                    stop = middle - 1;
                    middle = Math.floor(start + (stop - start) / 2);
                }
                console.log('New bounds: ' + start + '-' + stop);
                console.log('New middle: ' + middle);
            }
            alert("Your answer is : " + middle);
        }
    }
}
```

See on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLh3m12t/2/).

Comment: in this line (var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value, 10), what does the 10 mean?

Comment: @Barnabee It means base 10 (decimal). For example, if you put 16 there instead, it would parse the input as hexadecimal. The default is 10, *unless* the number given begins with a 0, in which case *some* implementations use base 8 (or 16 if it starts with 0x) ([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)).

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the variable middle in the while loop in binary search. Thus the middle value always remains 50.

Add this at start of while loop
`middle = start + (stop - start)/2`

Answer (score 0):

Every time you go through the `while(start <= stop)` loop, you never update `middle` to be in the middle of start and stop, it will always be at the value of 50.

So let's look at an example:

Here are your starting values:

```
start = 0
stop = 100
middle = (100+0)/2 = 50
guess = 23
```

Your code enters your while loop. Since middle > guess, your else if code will run:

```
stop = middle -1;
```

So the value of stop now is 50-1 = 49. Your while loop repeats, and since middle, and guess haven't chagned,  the same line  of code will fire off: `stop = middle -1;` which will just cause your stop to be equal to 49 again. And it will loop infinitely like this.

What you need to do is reset middle at the end of the while loop:

```
middle = (start + stop)/2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just make a function and test it against the input value. First let's do something with that HTML:

```
<input type='text' value='', id='number' />
<input type='button' value='play game' id='game' />
<div id='result'>To play the game press the button.</div>
```

Now on an External JavaScript page that should be accessed through the script tags `src` attribute:

```
var pre = onload;
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();
var doc = document;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function numberGame(numberElement, start, finish){
  var u = +numberElement.value, r = '';
  if(u < start){
    r = 'Number was too low.'; numberElement.focus()
  }
  else if(u < finish){
    r = 'Number was too high.'; numberElement.focus();
  }
  else if(u === Math.floor(Math.random()*(finish+1))){
    r = 'It&#039;s  a match!';
  }
  else{
    r = 'Try again.'; numberElement.focus();
  }
  return r;
}
E('game').onclick = function(){
  E('result').innerHTML = numberGame(E('number'), 0, 100);
}
}
```